# How to get value from ComboBox and TextBox into Argument line?

Tags: vb.net

I want to unzip a specific file with a external Program in VB.NET but, I don't know how to do that. 
This is my attempt.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Process.Start("7z.exe","-e" Textbox1.Text + Combobox1.Text )
End Sub
```

Comment: And in what way does this attempt not work as expected?  What is the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the 7z.exe use the DLL they provide.

```
Public Class ArchivationHandling
Private Declare Function SevenZip Lib "7-zip32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal strCmdLine As String, ByVal strOutput As String, ByVal dwSize As Integer) As Long
Private bJobCompleted As Boolean = False
Private Const ZIP_EXTENSION As String = ".zip"
Private Const SEVEN_ZIP_PAR As String = vbNullString
Private Function Decompress(ByVal strZipPath As String, ByVal strOutPut As String) As Boolean
    Dim strZipComm As String = "x -o" & strOutPut & " " & strZipPath & ZIP_EXTENSION & " -hide"
    Try
        SevenZip(0, strZipComm, SEVEN_ZIP_PAR, 0)
        bJobCompleted = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Logger.WriteLogEntry(4, "Decompression failed for file: " & strZipPath & " " & ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
    Return bJobCompleted
End Function
Public ReadOnly Property Decompression(ByVal strZipFilePath As String, ByVal strOutput As String) As Boolean
    Get
        Return Decompress(strZipFilePath, strOutput)
    End Get
End Property
```

End Class

This is an example of what I use in one of my applications.
You just provide the input file and output.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion with 7z.exe. I want to know how to get like in Command Prompt custom environment variables for vb.net.